# grep's at sign caught as whitespace

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, grep

I ran into a problem while trying to grep a file that contains the following:

```
@abc
abc
 abc

@abc@
 @abc@ 
 @abc@
acb
abc@
assd
dsasd
abc@
```

I tried various grep commands, but there was a problem and abc@ or @abc were caught as whitespace in my regexps. I want the output, in general, to simulate the following script's output (only the "Good" ones):

`for res in $(grep -F 'abc' test.txt); do if [[ ! $res == *@* ]]; then echo $res is good; else echo $res is bad; fi; done`

Comment: what does "were caught as whitespace" mean?

Comment: actually nothing, looking in my .bash_history (funny enough using grep...) I just mixed the operators and caught stuff that were supposed to be caught...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No -P needed; -E is sufficient:

```
grep -E '(^|\s)abc(\s|$)'
```

or even without -E:

```
grep '\(^\|\s\)abc\(\s\|$\)'
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time with Google I asked on the [ask ubuntu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) chat room.

A [user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/5891/djeikyb) there was king enough to help me find the solution I was looking for and i wanted to share so that any following suers running into this may find it:

`grep -P "(^|\s)abc(\s|$)"` gives the result I was looking for. -P is an **experimental** implementation of perl regexps.

grepping for `abc` and then using filters like `grep -v '@abc'` (this is far from perfect...) should also work, but my patch does something similar.